# How to rewrite the method ( e.g. created ... ) of vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

use the vue-cli to created demo

index.js code

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

// not work !!!
App.created = function () {
    console.log(1231231232);   
}

Vue.config.productionTip = true

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

i don`t want to use`extend`，because it will exec twice

Comment: This worked when I tried it. What exactly isn't working? `1231231232` doesn't get logged?

Comment: it did not print out anything, and i tried it on two pc, it was the same situation.

vue-cli version 2.8.1